# getObjectInBackgroundWithID for parse but having a "cannot invoke with argument type" error in Swift

Tags: swift

So I am trying to get an object from Parse and it's giving me an error regarding optional that I can't quite figure out.  The error is involved with `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` portion and I can't quite figure out why my unwrappings are not working.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var question: String!
var answers: [String]!
var answer: String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.



}

func CallData() {
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("myParseCode") {
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject?, error : NSError?)-> Void in
        // error is here^^
        if (error == nil) {
            self.question = objectHolder["Question"] as? String
            self.answers = objectHolder["Answers"] as? Array
            self.answer = objectHolder["Answer"] as? String

            if (self.answers?.count > 0) {
                self.questionLabel.text = self.question
            }

        } else {
            println("Theres been an error")
        }

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
```

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: cannot assign a value of type string to a value of string!

Comment: I think I know what the problem is based on that error (see my amended answer). You basically need to make sure the values you're extracting are unwrapped before assigning them.

Comment: Thanks man but now it is saying argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be defined at the Array Answers.  I'll try to do my own research some more but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the string is unwrapped before assigning it to your class property, as you've stated that is non-optional (with the `!`). You can use [optional binding](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/) by replacing the following lines of code in what you've provided:

```
self.question = objectHolder["Question"] as? String
self.answers = objectHolder["Answers"] as? Array
self.answer = objectHolder["Answer"] as? String
```

with:

```
if let question = objectHolder["Question"] as? String {
    self.question = question //it's now unwrapped and not an optional
}

if let answers = objectHolder["Answers"] as? Array {
    self.answers = answers
}

if let answer = objectHolder["Answer"] as? String {
    self.answer = answer
}
```